# How do I implement Facebook Authentication using Parse in Xamarin Cross Platform Solution?

Tags: c#, facebook, mobile, parse-platform, xamarin

I'm creating a cross platform mobile application for a local food truck for my senior project. I specifically want to use Parse for it's User class because there will be multiple roles. I'm having trouble with implementing Facebook authentication with Parse. For some reason, I keep getting an error that I can't access JsonValue. Can anyone give me some guidance?
Here is a link to my git repository, if that would help. https://github.com/mkmcgreal/FoodTruck.git

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

using Parse;
using System.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Auth;

namespace FoodTruck.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "Food Truck", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        //int count = 1;
        public void LoginToFacebook (bool allowCancel)
        {

            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
                clientId: "**************",
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

            auth.AllowCancel = allowCancel;

            // If authorization succeeds or is canceled, .Completed will be fired.
            auth.Completed += LoginComplete;

//          UIViewController vc = auth.GetUI ();
//          PresentViewController (vc, true, null);
        }

        public async void LoginComplete( object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e )
        {
            // We presented the UI, so it's up to us to dismiss it.
            //DismissViewController (true, null);

            if (!e.IsAuthenticated) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Not Authorised");
                return;
            }

            var accessToken = e.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
            var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(e.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
            var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds( expiresIn );

            // Now that we're logged in, make a OAuth2 request to get the user's id.
            var request = new OAuth2Request ("GET", new Uri ("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, e.Account);
            request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith (t => {
                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
                if (t.IsFaulted) 
                {
                    builder.SetTitle ("Error");
                    builder.SetMessage (t.Exception.Flatten().InnerException.ToString());
                } 
                else if (t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    builder.SetTitle ("Task Canceled");
                ]
                else {
                var obj = JsonValue.Parse (t.Result.GetResponseText());
                var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"","");
                var user = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(id, accessToken,expiryDate);

                builder.SetTitle ("Logged in");
                builder.SetMessage ("Name: " + obj["name"]);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            Xamarin.Insights.Initialize (global::FoodTruck.Droid.XamarinInsights.ApiKey, this);

            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            StartActivity (auth.GetUI (this));

//          var facebook = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.FacebookButton);           
//          facebook.Click += delegate { LoginToFacebook(true);};
//
//          var facebookNoCancel = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.FacebookButtonNoCancel);
//          facebookNoCancel.Click += delegate { LoginToFacebook(false);};
            //};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I am not using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Is it a runtime error, or compile time?  What is the *exact* error message?  Which line does the error occur on?  Finally, delete the commented out code, it's distracting to read.  Bonus: try using JSON.NET, it is much more robust and friendly than System.Json.